# Something up with Stack Exchange's servers lately?

Tags: support, stackexchange-2.0, performance, server

Sorry, I didn't know where else to post this, but is there something going on with Stack Exchange's servers lately? The Stack Exchange sites have been pretty poor performers for the past couple weeks.

EDIT: More details: basically even just going to stackoverflow.com makes my browser sit there, loading & loading. Sometimes hitting ESC to stop loading and going to the URL again will work. There are also random stalls (as users noted below) while upvoting comments, etc. I'm in a major metropolitan city with a fast connection, and all other sites are blazing fast.

Comment: Anecdotally, I have noticed that the response to certain actions (e.g. closing a question) has been getting randomly stalled, but I can't point to anything specific.

Comment: Specifying your location might help. Could be the recent switch to a CDN.

Comment: "Sorry, I didn't know where else to post this" -- this is exactly the right place to post this. However, a few more details would be helpful.

Comment: @balpha Details added.

Comment: According to Chrome inspector, the trouble lies with accessing files on cdn.sstatic.net, which took a whopping 6 seconds!! And these are just small files, 15k, 50k, etc.